# Android Room - Create custom index

Tags: android, indexing, android-sqlite, android-room

I migrate my database from DBFlow to Room finally.

However, some queries I made for my old database don't really match what I know about Room. So in my Entity I have / had these calls:

```
"CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `idDeletedStartEndLocalIndex` ON `QUANTITY`(START_LOCAL, END_LOCAL DESC)"
```

I implemented that in Room as

```
Index("START_LOCAL", "END_LOCAL")
```

but how can I add the **Descending** at the index? Should I just write "END_LOCAL DESC"? Would that work as expected?

Same for this one

```
"CREATE UNIQUE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `serverQtyId` ON QUANTITY(SERVER_QUANTITY_ID) WHERE SERVER_QUANTITY_ID > 0"
```

How can I add the **WHERE SERVER_QUANTITY_ID > 0** clause to the Index annotation of room? Is that even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looks like there are not many ways around this. So I did the queries manually.

For those who have the same problem, my code looks like this:

```
runBlocking(Dispatchers.IO){
   with (getInstance().openHelper.writableDatabase) {
       execSQL("CREATE INDEX IF NOT EXISTS `someIndexName` ON `QUANTITY`(...)")
       ...
   }
}
```

So what I do is basically **get the Database Instance** and their **openHelper**. From there you can **get the writable Database**. It then supports executing SQL queries directly.

All this is run in the IO coroutine scope but that's just for convenience.

Comment: In my experience, Room does not permit custom indexes to exist.  If you run a database migration, the database will no longer be openable.

Comment: So far it seems to work fine. Any specific example or hint where to look at?

Comment: Add a MigrationSpec to delete a column, then Room can't be used for any table.  The stack trace claims the migration had an error, but the runtime error goes away if you manually run the necessary DROP INDEX statements outside of Room.

Comment: java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception while computing database live data.
        at androidx.room.RoomTrackingLiveData$1.run(RoomTrackingLiveData.java:92)
        ...
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Migration didn't properly handle: MyEntity(com.MyEntity).
     Expected:
    TableInfo{name='MyTable', columns={...}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[...]}
     Found:
    TableInfo{name='MyTable', columns={...}, foreignKeys=[], indices=[..................]}
        at androidx.room.RoomOpenHelper.onUpgrade(RoomOpenHelper.java:103)
        ...